# C++ не работает чтение с файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Перепробовал весь код с интернета, разные способы, вводил полный/относительный путь к файлу, но код дальше файл не открывает, не проходит проверку открыт ли файл. Что может быть не так?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  ifstream inf("students.txt");
  while ( inf )
    {
        string val = "";
        inf >> val;
        cout << val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы работаете с Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто из любопытства, попробуйте код, который точно должен работать:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream inf("students.txt", std::ifstream::in);

  char c = inf.get();

  while (inf.good())
  {
    std::cout << c;
    c = inf.get();
  }

  inf.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Запустил. Не работает://

Comment: @shumik_UA возможно: полный корректный путь к файлу со всем escape кодированием, права доступа программы на файл.

Comment: совсем ничего не работает. Уже и полный путь вставлял

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста:
1) код уже с полным путем к файлу
2) какие аттрибуты файла у students.txt
3) это Linux/Windows?

Comment: #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream inf("D:\\NULP\\OP\\Лаби\\10\\01\\students.txt", std::ifstream::in);

  char c = inf.get();

  while (inf.good())
  {
    std::cout << c;
    c = inf.get();
  }

  inf.close();

  return 0;
}

Comment: Windows, а какие атрибуты?

Comment: @shumik_UA Возможно у программы (или у запускающего ее процесса, например, у Visual Studio) нет доступа к этой директории или к этому файлу

Comment: Это один срр файл который запускаю через обычный gcc. Текстовый файл в той же директории, самый обычный и со всеми правами

Comment: Получить код ошибки:

if( inf.fail() )
{
std::cerr << "Error: " << std::strerror(errno);
}

Или посмотреть обсуждение здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337602/how-to-get-error-message-when-ifstream-open-fails

Comment: Скорее всего эти `Лаби` не понимает - не в той кодировке, например, задано, несоответствие исходника и на диске... Поместите куда-то, где в пути не будет русских букв, и попробуйте еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения. Создал текстовый файл в другой идентичной папке, а в пути была разница в 1 цифру, мой косяк. Спасибо всем, кто отписал